# check if cart item has the same property

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am using the codeigniter cart library, but now the client wants users to only be able to checkout items from one category at at a time because of some issues with their payment gateway.
Current the site has a single checkout logic for all categories.
When a users adds an items to the cart, i have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [d8df18561040f3d9bd9868f5c5aaa7c2] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => d8df18561040f3d9bd9868f5c5aaa7c2
            [id] => MYU_SC1
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 500
            [name] => WAEC Scratch Card
            [service_image] => assets/img/waec.jpg
            [service_category] => scratch_cards
            [subtotal] => 500
        )

    [99483fe03da62c9e98ce71232998f447] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 99483fe03da62c9e98ce71232998f447
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [size] => 36
                    [colour] => N/A
                )

            [id] => 80433426a546064bf5f8d09a6e7fdabc
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 5000
            [name] => Green Vee Jeans
            [service_image] => http://localhost/myunivacity/uploads/apparels/IMG_0425.JPG
            [service_category] => apparels
            [subtotal] => 5000
        )

)
```

how i do check if whether or not the items in the cart have same value for "service_category" element?. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with something like this:

```
<?php 

$categories = array();

foreach($this->cart->contents() as $cart_item) {
    if(!isSet($categories[$cart_item["service_category"]]) {
        $categories[$cart_item["service_category"]] = 1;        
    }
    else {
        $categories[$cart_item["service_category"]]++;
    }
}

print_r($categories);

?>
```

This fills an array with a count per category